# Service media.camera didn't start

Tags: android, camera, android-service

I can't open the camera since my phone went flat once. (even installed camera2 on magisk)

logcat shows it trying to connect and does this cycle every couple of sections

```
03-05 16:57:26.449 25035 25139 W ServiceManager: Service media.camera didn't start. Returning NULL
03-05 16:57:26.912  5778  5858 I CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
03-05 16:57:27.912  5778  5858 I CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
03-05 16:57:28.912  5778  5858 I CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
03-05 16:57:29.725  2563  2595 W ServiceManager: Service media.camera didn't start. Returning NULL
03-05 16:57:29.913  5778  5858 I CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
03-05 16:57:30.129  2742  2742 F linker  : CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/system/bin/cameraserver": library "libc++_shared.so" not found
```

found this when i launched the camera app

```
03-05 17:04:41.387  4793 11362 D ShortcutManager: th = 1 is camera package
```

and dumpsys returns

```
Can't find service: media.camera
```

Comment: May I know how to set `FileProvider.getUriForFile();` when you open camera?

Comment: What exactly did you do when your phone went flat?  Something with the phone is very wrong, the camera service process can't start because it can't find its libraries. That should never happen on a normal phone OS version.